# Neo4J Return column alias (AS) name with space, is it possible?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, alias

Using Neo4J 2.1.6 with Cypher.

I was wondering if it's possible to "**alias**" a query result column with a string **containing spaces**?

Following code generates error:

[image]

error with "..."

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN a.name AS "My Alias Column Name";
```

error without ...

```
MATCH a 
RETURN a.name AS My Alias Column Name;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spaces are possible, you can alias it using the backticks as follows:

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN a.age AS `My Alias Age Column Name`;
```

Comment: MATCH a RETURN a.age AS \`My Alias Column Name\`